# java javaMail NoClassDefFoundError on Message msg = new MimeMessage(session)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, message

I am going around and around.

I have code that has worked fine, It has been 6 months to a year since I have used it. I attempted to run it and am now getting: NoClassDefFoundError . This is involved with building / sending an email.

I have broken out a debug snip-it and have narrowed things down to the line:

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session)

I am using JAVA 13 and Netbeans 11. I am not using Maven. I have found many threads with the solutions but none are working for me.

I have found and read the top StakeOverflow hits for this very problem but I must be doing something wrong with my solution - not using Maven I am seeing  the set classpath as the path but after different attempts still getting the error. Some threads seem too old to apply. The code has worked and is right out of the typical sample code to send emails.

I have tried jvax.mail and javax.mail-1.62

https://javaee.github.io/javamail/
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/SMTP-Transport

I have chased setting classpaths per several threads
I have these lines in my environment variable:

C:\Users\xyz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JAR Files\JavaX-mail_com.sun
C:\Users\xyz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JAR Files\JAVA_Mail

Help?

Oh, what has changed since it worked - upgraded to Windows 10 and that required me to upgrade JAVA and Netbeans

The code: (is this enough)

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

public void debugEmail(){

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");   
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");

    properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port","587");


        //Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

The above code is where I created a debug routine breaking about / creating a simple routine, it narrows down the NoClassDefFound error to the Message msg = line

Comment: Why have you decided not to use Maven? This is exactly the tool to manage dependencies.

Comment: Could you post the complete error. You did'nt post the name of the class that is not found

Comment: Oh, what has changed since it worked - upgraded to Windows 10 and that required me to upgrade JAVA and Netbeans ... I have never used Maven and because of this problem am just finding out about it.. I am needing to just get this code back running (quickly),

Comment: Also, check with Java 8. Recent JDKs have removed some modules

Comment: Exactly how are you setting the class path and exactly how are you invoking your program?

Comment: To be clear, the CLASSPATH environment variable needs to contain the name of the jar file for JavaMail.  You'll probably also need activation.jar if you're using JDK 11.

Comment: I have a jButton that calls this routine to isolate the problem. For the classpath, I followed a procedure to go into control panel .. variables and so forth

Comment: I am not following you on your last comment, " the CLASSPATH environment variable needs to contain the name of the jar file for JavaMail. You'll probably also need activation.jar if you're using JDK 11.

Comment: per Boris (and of course others) I have started a Maven Project. I have never used Maven. However, by following a basic getting started page, I can now run the exact same code with no error. Unfortunately my Netbeans environment is VERY slow with the Maven project, any thoughts on how to use the fact that the maven project runs to fix my original?

Comment: sort of real time ... I have successfully sent an email using my old code that was copied and pasted into my new Maven project. I cannot explain what I did other than follow an example regarding Maven. I can explain my original JAVA code ...

Answer (score 0):

The code is now working - i converted things to a Maven java project and appended the Maven xml file with my various libraries